# Can't get variables to interact with one another (C++)

Tags: c++

Alright, so I've been trying to code this program, its supposed to create an array of 10,000 numbers randomly generated between 1 and 500.  Afterwards it needs to ask the user for a number (between 1-500) and tell you how many times was this number found in the array.

After some help here earlier i got my array to well, work, but i seem to fail to understand something else.  When i try to compare the user input to the array something doesn't work and I'm not sure what it is.

Here's the code:

```
// AmountOfNum is supposed to represent how many times does the GuessedNum appears in the array
// GuessedNum is simply the user input
// randonum is supposed to act as the numbers in the array in the main function
// The NumGen function is supposed to turn all the numbers in the array into randomized number between 1-500
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
std::random_device seed;
std::mt19937 mersenneTwister(seed());
const int AmountOfNum = 10000;

int RandomInt(int min, int max);
int NumGen(int numss);
int Numguessed(int guess);

int main()
{
    int AmountOfNum = 0;
    int GuessedNum = 0;
    int randonum = 0;
    cin >> GuessedNum;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        int randonum = NumGen(AmountOfNum);
        //Just to see what numbers are generated, probably want to remove this once its done
        cout << randonum << "\n";
    }

    if (GuessedNum = randonum)
     {
        AmountOfNum++;
     }

    cout << AmountOfNum;
}

 int RandomInt(int min, int max)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min, max);
    return distribution(mersenneTwister);
}

int NumGen(int numss)
{
    std::vector <int> numsinarray(AmountOfNum);

    for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfNum; i++)
    {
        numsinarray[i] = RandomInt(1, 500);
        return numsinarray[i];

    }
}
```

Now, if i include the if statement in my for loop (in main), the AmountOfNum always ends up being 10,000.  If i put it outside of the for loop, it is always 0.

The answer is probably quite obvious but for the life of me i cannot figure it out.

Comment: `if (GuessedNum = randonum)` should be `==`

Comment: There are two AmountOfNum variable. Rename one of them to avoid confusion

Comment: changing `=` to `==`did not seem to change anything.  Also i cant find the second `AmountOfNum` in the code, where is it located?

Comment: @HalpPlease "_changing `=` to `==` did not seem to change anything._" This is a lie. It, at the very least, changed the assignment from `randomnum`, to `GuessedNum`, to comparison of `randomnum`, to `GuessedNum`.

Comment: oh, I did not realize that.  Apologies

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple fundamental bugs in the shown code, every one of them is fatal and as a result of that, the results of the program will not be what you intended.

Bug #1:

In your main():

```
int randonum = 0;
```

This declares a local variable called `randomnum` and sets it to 0.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    int randonum = NumGen(AmountOfNum);

    // ...
}
```

The `for` loop declares a new inner variable named `randonum`, and sets it to whatever `NumGen()` returns. Nothing else is done to this `randomnum` except showing its value, after which point the loop ends, and this `randonum` gets destroyed. The original `randonum`, declared in the outer scope, is still 0, like it always was. Declaring another variable with the same name in an inner scope creates an independent variable that has nothing to do with the original one.

Bug #2:

```
 if (GuessedNum = randonum)
```

This `randonum` is still 0. See bug #1. `=` is an assignment operator. This ends up assigning 0 to `GuessedNum`. Since the result is always a logical false, since `randonum` is still 0, this `if` statement will always evaluate to false.

Bug #3:

In your `NumGen` function:

```
std::vector <int> numsinarray(AmountOfNum);
```

This declares a new vector. Fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i < AmountOfNum; i++)
{
    numsinarray[i] = RandomInt(1, 500);
    return numsinarray[i];
```

Inside the `for` loop, `numsinarray[i]` gets set to the return value from `RandomInt`. Then this function returns this value.

Grand total: on the very first iteration of the loop, with the initial value of `i` being 0, this ends up setting `numsinarray[0]` to the return value from `RandomInt`, and then immediately returns the same value, without bothering to do anything about the rest of the vector.

Why was an entire vector declared in the first place? What's the purpose of the `for` loop, attempting to iterate over the entire vector, but only ending up iterating once, calling `RandomInt` once, setting the first value of the vector, and then returning that value?

Whatever that's supposed to accomplish, this is obviously incorrect, and is another bug.

These are the three fundamental bugs that were obvious from a cursory examination of your code. Remember the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming:

> A computer always does exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what
>   you want it to do

You told your computer:

1. Call `NumGen`() ten thousand times.
2. Print each value returned from `NumGen`(), but not save it anywhere, and just throw each value away.
3. Inside `Numgen()` create a vector with ten thousand values, start iterating over all values, but as soon as the first random value gets generated return it, and destroy the vector.
4. The `if` statement assigns a variable that's always 0 to another value, which will never be true, so that `if` statement will never be true.
5. There's nothing in the shown code that actually saves all randomly-generated values anywhere. After each one is generated, it gets shown and gets thrown away.

And your computer does exactly what you told it to do. If you want your computer to do something else, you need to change your code to tell your computer exactly what it should do.

Comment: oh I see, i think I understand for the first and second bug.  The third one still leaves me confused however.  How should i go about it to get all the int in the array to be assigned a randomized value?  The reason i used the vector to begin with was because i was not able to use it in any function as its size exceeded the function's. someone told me to use vectors as a solution.

Edit: If I try to run the program it'll give me 10 thousand randomized numbers, which leads me to being even more confused

Comment: If you want "all the int in the array to be assigned a randomized value" then you need to write the code to do that, instead of writing some code that creates the vector, sets the first value in the vector to one random value, returns that random value, destroying the vector, and then execute the whole thing ten thousand times. This is not logically equivalent to "all the int in the array to be assigned a randomized value". As I pointed out to you: a computer does exactly, and precisely, what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do.